# Python Gtk3 create cell of treeview with a color field

Tags: python, gtk3

I want to fill a cell of a treeview with a color field and searching for a good method to do this.

Here is what I have tried already:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Gdk, GdkPixbuf


window = Gtk.Window()
window.set_default_size(300, 100)
window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
window.set_title("CellRendererPixbuf in GTK3")

box = Gtk.HBox()
window.add(box)

liststore = Gtk.ListStore(GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf)
pix = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new(GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB, True, 8, 10, 10)
liststore.append([pix])
treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=liststore)
renderer_pixbuf = Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf().new()
column_pixbuf = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Color", renderer_pixbuf, stock_id=0)
treeview.append_column(column_pixbuf)

box.pack_start(treeview, True, True, 0)

window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: I think the question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38771311/drawing-a-custom-gdkpixbuf-using-gtk3-and-cairo

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

Finally I got it working now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import GdkPixbuf

window = Gtk.Window()
window.set_default_size(300, 100)
window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
window.set_title("CellRendererPixbuf in GTK3")

box = Gtk.HBox()
window.add(box)

# creat liststore
liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str, GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf)

pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new(GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB, False, 8, 32, 16)
pixbuf.fill(0xff0000) 
liststore.append(["Green", pixbuf])

pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new(GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB, False, 8, 32, 16)
pixbuf.fill(0x00ff00) 
liststore.append(["Blue", pixbuf])

pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new(GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB, False, 8, 32, 16)
pixbuf.fill(0x000000) 
liststore.append(["Black", pixbuf])

# create treeview
treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=liststore)

# create text column
renderer_text = Gtk.CellRendererText()
column_text = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Text", renderer_text, text=0)
treeview.append_column(column_text)

# create pixbuf column
renderer_pixbuf = Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf().new()
column_pixbuf = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Color", renderer_pixbuf, pixbuf=1)
treeview.append_column(column_pixbuf)

# pack
box.pack_start(treeview, True, True, 0)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```